# PostgreSQL group data by month AND type

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, crosstab

I have a table which goes something like this:

```
ID    item_type    date
1      apple        2016-12-01       
2      banana       2016-12-01      
3      banana       2016-12-01
```

and so on. What I need to do is get an output table with months as rows, and item_type as columns, and the count of number of entries for each combo so that it looks something like

```
month    apple     banana       
dec      1         2
```

and so on... I've tried `date_trunc` for the monthly grouping but that seems to be giving me the count on basis of date not month! And I'm not sure how to do the multiple grouping at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select date_trunc('month', date) as mon,
       sum((item_type = apple)::int) as apple,
       sum((item_type = banana)::int) as banana
from t
group by mon
order by mon;
```

Comment: Thank you, this works for the apples and bananas part (which I was really having trouble with!) but the date_trunc part is giving output as a timestamp (for 1st of the month) with time zone. Could extract work to give just the month (as a number or otherwise)?

Comment: @Shisa . . . Yes, `extract()` is fine for that purpose.  You mentioned `date_trunc()` in the question and I prefer to include the year with the month.

Comment: @gordon_linoff btw is there any way to do this without having to mention each particular item in the query but rather just do two different group by and count bys - 1 for rows and 1 for columns? What if I don't know the details on how many item_types are available in the database or if the number of item_types is large and unwieldy to code individually??

Comment: @Shisa . . . If you don't know the items, you have a different problem.  I would suggest that you google "Postgres dynamic pivot".

Answer (score 1):

irrelevant tip but I would also not use "date" as the column name as it's a reserved word in pgsql.

Comment: yup :) that's not the real col name, just used it as a placeholder. but noted, thanks!

Comment: Can't yet add comments here :D but you probably can use date_part( too, it's the equivalent of extract() mentioned above, fyi https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-datetime.html

Answer (score 0):

Btw, if I am not mistaken, the query should be like this:

```
select date_trunc('month', date) as mon,
       sum((item_type = 'apple')::int) as apple,
       sum((item_type = 'banana')::int) as banana
from t
group by mon
order by mon;
```

To avoid Postgres to issue an error, since I assume "item_type" is stored as a string variable.